# Cannot run tool after installation via command line

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, eslint, sublimelinter

I'm trying to install ESLint via the command line, but it's failing to be recognized after I successfully install it.  I followed the instructions to install it globally via the manual below. The path in which it's located is: (`Users/(my username)/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/eslint`). Typing anything containing 'eslint' after that yields: "zsh: command not found: eslint."

I'm guessing it could have been installed to the wrong location..?  Or something to do with my shell (I'm using oh-my-zsh).  I'm just learning to use the command line, so I realize this is a very basic question - I just don't know where to begin trouble shooting this.

http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

It seems like eslint is not in your PATH, try accessing eslint via the full path. Or by adding the location to your PATH.

```
Users/(my username)/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/eslint
```

Comment: Yes, I can access the contents of ESLint using the current path, but I'd think moving it to my $PATH is a more sustainable solution (if I continue running ESLint on each of my js files).

My PATH is located here: `/Users/christinechou/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`  so, to copy (or move?) the file to this PATH location, would it be correct to type into the command line:

```cp `Users/(my username)/... /node_modules/eslint`  `$PATH`?```

Comment: I found another useful response to a similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/adding-a-new-executable-to-the-path-environment-variable

It looks like I can also leave the file where it is and symlink it from one of the PATH directories.